# Reading excel file inside the user.dir

Tags: java, eclipse

Is this a good way of locating in terms of portability? My excel file is placed under *src* folder in eclipse.

```
public void testFile() throws Exception {

 ReadExcelFile file = new ReadExcelFile ();

//Read keyword sheet

Sheet TestSheet = file.readExcel(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\","TestCase.xlsx" , 
"Sheet1");
}
```

Comment: So, you expect each and every user of your application to name the file "TestCase.xlsx", to create an src directory in the directory from where they execute the app, and to place the excel file there? Why don't you let the user pass the file to open as argument instead? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You should write it more universally, like this:

```
public void testFile(String pathToFile, String filename, String sheet) throws Exception {

    ReadExcelFile file = new ReadExcelFile ();

    //Read keyword sheet

    Sheet TestSheet = file.readExcel(pathFoFile, filename, sheet);
}
```

Hope that is want you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven for this application and your intent is to unit test this against a Sample XLS file everytime....  then consider placing the Test case file under src/test/resources.

This way:
- you will be able to unit test on every build
- The test case XLS will not get bundled with your JAR (if you want it bundled then place it under src/main/resources)

If this is something that the application needs to use in production, I would recommend passing it as a parameter to this application.

Hope this helps :)